# Node.js app has high CPU usage due to `spawn`, how can I log all calls to it?

Tags: c++, node.js, cpu-usage, v8, child-process

My Node.js (we are running v6.9.5) app often has > 80% CPU usage (happened on v4 also). After doing some basic profiling, it appears that it is spawning a lot of child processes:

```
[Summary]:
  ticks   total  nonlib  name
    345    6.7%    6.9%  JavaScript
   4451   86.7%   89.1%  C++
     82    1.6%    1.6%  GC
    136    2.6%          Shared libraries
    201    3.9%          Unaccounted

----------

[C++]:
 ticks   total  nonlib  name
  2606   50.8%   52.2%  node::ProcessWrap::Spawn(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
   319    6.2%    6.4%  node::ContextifyScript::New(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
   284    5.5%    5.7%  syscall
   111    2.2%    2.2%  write
    31    0.6%    0.6%  void node::StreamBase::JSMethod<node::StreamWrap, &(int
```

I have added logging to all of our app-specific `child_process.spawn` / `exec` / `execFile` calls, but none of those explain why the CPU is spending so much time on it.

I would like to now log all the calls of `child_process` within all the `node_modules` that we use, in case there is a module that sends too many calls due to some bug, over-eager executing of callbacks, or some other misuse on our part.

Initially I thought to create `child_process` wrapper module with added logging, and hope that our dependencies would use that in favor of Node.js' native module, unfortunately the dependencies seem to keep using the native module.

Question:

- How can I add logging on all the `spawn` calls of my process? Or is there a better way to get more insight into what part of our app is causing the spawns?

In case I'm off completely:

- Could there be a different reason for `node::ProcessWrap::Spawn(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)` to consume relatively so many CPU ticks, other than `child_process` calls?

Any clue is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could start node with --trace flag. This will cause in-built method tracing to be turned on, and one line per method call will be printed in the console with the call-depth, call-name, script location, parameters, caller's info, callee's info etc. placed contextual to the call.

So you would actually count the number of instances of `spawn` in the trace to determine how much calls were made. Second, before each spawn call, you would traverse backward in the call-depth chain to see the call-heirarchy to figure our how and where in your application the spawn calls were originated.

Hope this helps!